# Python Windows: correct virtualenv paths

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

I'm new to virtualenv and not sure how to set up paths. My paths have been set to something like this:

```
PYTHONPATH=C:\Python27\
PYTHONSTARTUP=C:\Python27\Scripts\startup.py
PATH=%PYTHONPATH%;...;%PYTHONPATH%\Scripts
```

Should I remove those paths for virtualenv's activate script to work correctly? If I can keep my paths then how do I call scripts for an env when it has been activated? Do I call scripts by explicitly running them with python.exe instead of simply typing the script name alone?

```
python myscript.py
```

Not sure how to handle the paths and I would appreciate a little guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have your paths wrong. `PYTHONPATH` tells Python in what folders to look for Python modules and normally you don't put Python's installation folder in it. For keeping installation folder of Python there's different environment variable called `PYTHONHOME`. So instead of `PYTHONPATH=C:\Python27\` you should have `PYTHONHOME=C:\Python27\`. You should change `PATH` variable to use `PYTHONHOME` accordingly.

As to how to set environment variables when working with *virtualenv*; you don't need to do anything because *virtualenv* stores original values when it's activated, modifies environment variables it needs to modify and then restores original values when it's deactivated.

You can take a look at [Using Python on Windows](http://docs.python.org/using/windows.html)

Answer (score -4):

Think you are fine just get on with virtual-env, (follow docs) but remember you must use cmd shell (NO POINT AND CLICKING!!) Took me a while before I realized that...

Once you have activated And installed what you want to in the virtual env,, you invoke scripts by "python scriptname"

Comment: Are you confirming that my environment paths are correctly set and don't need to be changed?

Comment: <<tap, tap, tap>> Is this thing on?

Comment: Sorry you have exceeded my ability to help, don't know what platform you are on and what you really have done so can't be more specific. Suggest go back to whatever doc you were using and follow step by step again. :-(

Comment: It was tagged "python", "windows", "virtualenv" from the start.